# What is the equivalent of HTTPClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, kerberos, windows-authentication

I have Linux machines joined to the domain and need to pass NTLM or Kerberos machine authentication to a background service using [Windows Integrated Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication).

How can I do this in Linux, preferably using Python?